# At what time do the dailies refresh in Skyforge?

Tags: skyforge

Like many free-to-play MMORPG, Skyforge offers a daily login bonus. When exactly does the day end though?

Comment: Note that the daily connection bonuses stop after the seventh day, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the other games produced by Allods Team have dailies resetting at 5 am pacific time (which is 12:00 Noon in GMT). From personal experience waking up at 5:30 am and going to bed at midnight every day. It's safe to say 5 am is the reset time.